# Scrape complete HTML tag wise

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, custom-selectors

Suppose I have an HTML page as

```
<p> Some text here </p>
<p> Some other text here </p>
<h1> Title 1 </h1>
<p> Another text here </p>
<p> Some random text here </p>
<h1> Title 2 </h1>
<p> Some text here </p>
<p> Some other text here </p>
<h1>..<h1>
```

Is it possible to scrape the content's tag by tag

```
if (<h1>)
then do something

if (<p>)
then do something else
```

For each of the tags

Comment: so what you're trying to do is you want to loop through ALL the html elements and do something for each of them?

Comment: Checkout Jsoup library (https://jsoup.org/apidocs/). It has lots of methods that will help you do the needful

Comment: @RandomDeveloper - yes i want to loop through each of the tags, and then apply the necessary conditions

Comment: I tried using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ , works good to get the <h1> tags as $article->find('h1')->plaintext

Comment: may be something like a html tags to array in php ?

Comment: i think you can use the function `getElementsByTagName('element')`

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) select element by name of tag. If you put `*` in function parameter, it return all elements.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element){
    if ($element->tagName == "h1")
        // do something
    if ($element->tagName == "p")
        // do something
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/jfeqe)